# Running Hadoop MapReduce, is it possible to call external executables outside of HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Within my mapper I'd like to call external software installed on the worker node outside of the HDFS.  Is this possible?  What is the best way to do this?

I understand that this may take some of the advantages/scalability of MapReduce away, but i'd like to interact both within the HDFS and call compiled/installed external software codes within my mapper to process some data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mappers (and reducers) are like any other process on the box- as long as the TaskTracker user has permission to run the executable, there is no problem doing so.  There are a few ways to call external processes, but since we are already in Java, [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) seems a logical place to start.

EDIT: Just found that Hadoop has a class explicitly for this purpose: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Shell.html

Comment: Just to add: Shell is package visible, you can't use them without beeing in the package.

Comment: Will the Shell class within java call a process on the node outside the HDFS?

Comment: @chris thanks - that works!  do you know how to set the TaskTracker user permissions?

Comment: The TaskTracker has to be running as a regular linux user.  In my clusters it is usually its own user (hadoop user or similar).  You just need to give that user permissions to do what you want.

Comment: The provided link is dead. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly doable.  You may find it best to work with [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html).  As it says on that website:

> Hadoop streaming is a utility that comes with the Hadoop distribution. The utility allows you to create and run map/reduce jobs with any executable or script as the mapper and/or the reducer.

I tend to start with external code inside of Hadoop Streaming.  Depending on your language, there are likely many good examples of how to use it in Streaming; once you get inside your language of choice, you can usually pipe data out to another program, if desired.  I have had several layers of programs in different languages playing nicely with no additional effort than if I had run it on a normal Linux box, beyond just getting the outer layer working with Hadoop Streaming.